# What's the difference between ReSharper `MergeSequentialChecks` and `MergeSequentialChecksWhenPossible`?

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-6.0

I'm trying to figure out what's the difference between these two rules?

- `MergeSequentialChecks`
- `MergeSequentialChecksWhenPossible`

The documentation doesn't say anything about the second one.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/MergeSequentialChecks.html

And it's not quire clear for me what does it mean `WhenPossible`?

If ReSharper suggests to apply the first rule and merge my sequential checks, then it IS possible indeed. How it could be not possible?

Here is a code example to check.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> Descendants { get; set; }
}

public static class TestReSharper
{
    // Here `MergeSequentialChecks` rule is triggered for both `&&` operands.
    public static bool MergeSequentialChecks(Person person)
    {
        return person != null && person.Descendants != null && person.Descendants.FirstOrDefault() != null;
    }

    // Here `MergeSequentialChecksWhenPossible` rule is triggered.
    public static bool MergeSequentialChecksWhenPossible1(Person person)
    {
        return person != null && person.Descendants.Any();
    }

    // Here `MergeSequentialChecksWhenPossible` rule is triggered.
    public static bool MergeSequentialChecksWhenPossible2(Person person)
    {
        return person.Descendants != null && person.Descendants.Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: note that the "Merge Sequential Checks" refactoring is broken in many cases, reversing the logic of your expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind code inspections with "(when possible)" label is simple: we decided not to suggest possible code transformation with the default R# settings, since produced code may result in reduced readability or became harder to understand. This decision on what to suggest or not is done via ad-hoc heuristics.

When we first implemented C# 6.0 related code suggestions and transformations and reviewed their results in big solutions available for us, we decided that nearly ~2/3 of occurrences of inspections like "Merge sequential checks" / "Use null propagation" should not suggest doing the code transformations. For example, we think that in the case of code like this:

```
if (node != null && node.IsValid()) { ... }
```

...there are no real benefits of using `?.` operator and introduction of "lifted" `operator==(bool, bool)` operator over value of `bool?` type:

```
if (node?.IsValid() == true) { ... }
```

Plus different devs have different views on how to check value of type `bool?` for being `true` (some prefer to have `?? false` instead, but that would make the resulting code `even?.more ?? questionable`).

So, the in the case above the merge of sequential checks is definitely "possible", but we are not gonna recommend it with the default R# settings (proper default settings is a huge responsibility), leaving user with the ability to see all cases by enabling the "(when possible)"-version of the same code inspection. As far I can see, currently we only check for not producing lifted boolean checks in "Merge sequential checks" inspection, other inspections have more heuristics, for example:

```
if (stringBuilder != null) { // "Use null propagation"
  stringBuilder.Append("hello");
}
```

Code above worth suggesting to use the conditional invocation operator:

```
stringBuilder?.Append("hello");
```

While using the conditional invocation twice or more times sequentially is questionable...

```
if (stringBuilder != null) { // no suggestion
  stringBuilder.Append("hello");
  stringBuilder.Append("world");
  stringBuilder.Append("!!!");
}
```

p.s. Context actions "Merge sequential checks" / "To null propagation" are *always* enabled when transformation is possible, despite the state of code inspections and their severities.

Comment: p.p.s. Strictly speaking, the existence of "(when possible)" versions of inspections is the result of absence of per-inspection settings, like in IntelliJ IDEA family of IDEs. We are looking to add per-inspection settings in future R# versions and merge "(when possible)"-versions of inspections with their corresponding ordinary inspections.