# Merge Sequential Check

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

There is a class `A` with Nullable property `Prop`

```
public class A {
    int? Prop {get; set;} 
}
```

...

I have object `a` which is type `A`
On the conditional:

```
if (a != null && a.Prop.HasValue) { // <--
   int res = a.Prop;
}
```

I am getting suggestion `"Merge sequential checks"`

I don't understand how could I do that. `a?.Prop.HasValue` will not work

What am I missing here?

Comment: `a?.Prop != null` is what it's talking about.  That or `a?.Prop.HasValue == true`

Comment: Just press alt+enter and apply suggested change, not sure why ask "how could I do that" if you can just apply suggested change (you can apply all suggested changes as far as I know, and certainly this one).

Comment: An if statement is parsed from left to right.  So if a is null, then a.Prop.HasValue is never performed.

Comment: These comments should be answers... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resharper converts your original logic:

```
if (a != null && a.Prop.HasValue)
```

into this:

```
if (a?.Prop != null)
```

So, the block will execute as long as the expression does not evaluate to `null`, and it will evaluate to `null` if either `a` is `null` (thanks to `?.`) or if `a.Prop` is `null` (as normal). In both versions, you're basically saying "do this stuff as long as both `a` and `a.Prop` have values" (or really "...don't not have values").

I'm not entirely sure I like these refactorings, though. Indeed, I can see [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240635/621316) that JetBrains themselves don't necessarily think these are good refactorings, because they make the code harder to understand.

In fact, I think probably specifically because these forms are harder to understand, this "Merge Sequential Checks" refactoring is actually **broken** in some cases, since at least [end of April 2017](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464629) ([also here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464561)), and still currently as of end of Feb 2018.

Beware when using the refactoring when your expression contains both an `||` operator, and either of the `Any` or `All` LINQ methods (and other cases, too, like a function call returning a `bool`).

Given:

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Resharper will convert this:

```
if (array == null || !array.Any())
```

into this:

```
if (!array?.Any() != true) // WRONG
```

The original was clearly "do this stuff if `array` is `null`, or if `array` is empty".

But what does the second version say? It's so hard to read you can barely tell if it's right or wrong.

`!= true` effectively means "do this if the expression was `null` or `false`". Ok, so we'll do it if `array` is null, that's good so far. But, if array is *not null*, then what?

Well, we want to do the stuff if the array is empty. If the array is empty, then `array?.Any()` will be `false`.

Then we have `!false`, which is `true`.

And then we have `true != true` which is `false`.

And so we have "if the array is empty ... *don't execute the block*", which is the opposite of what we wanted.

So Resharper has gotten the logic backwards, and the block will execute if there *is* a value, rather than if there is *not* a value.

Even without this flaw, the code is just plain hard to read, so I feel like this refactoring should generally be avoided.